# Using Node js to build realtime android app

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, real-time

I want to develop two apps which are related to each other. One is a postman app and another is for users who want to use postman's task.

I have been using node js server which uses socketio. I want to show couple of postmans in user app which they are in location constraint (define specific treshould). When the user taps his map and changes his position, postmans location should updated in user's map and show to them.

In order to design these apps, I had two scenarios in mind.

The first scenario I had, when user changes his position send his location to server and server should get postman's location which is in my defined treshold, but I think it's not optimal because when postmans move realtime in map, server should store their location and updated them and then fetch those to show in user app.

Second one is server broadcast to all postman's app and in postman's app side check treshould and if it's true send back his location to server.

Which of them would be appropriate to develop this situation?